# SQL Server 2012- Change in Datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have current date format in `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.ms` and I want result as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` format

I tried

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
```

but its not giving the result that I want.

Please help me as I'm a beginner in SQL Server.

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert the first format to the second, or do you just want to format `GETDATE()`?

Comment: Yes I just want to Format Getdate()

Comment: And want result as "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `FORMAT()` function (introduced in SQL 2012):

```
 SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'g')
 -- 8/25/2014 2:02 PM
```

Note, that the `FORMAT()` function doesn't perform very well, but it is handy for formatting in non-standard formats.

Update: Regarding the poor performance of `FORMAT()` as mentioned, since you're using `GETDATE()` and applying the same value to multiple records at a time, you can speed things up by storing the formatted date string in a variable and referencing that in your query:

```
DECLARE @Stamp VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'g'))
SELECT *, @Stamp dt
FROM YourTable
```

Ideally this sort of formatting wouldn't be done in SQL, but it's an ugly world we live in.

Comment: @user3617463 FORMAT() is horribly slow. But why not just format the data at the place where you're supposed to format data - the presentation tier?

Comment: @AaronBertrand.. Yeah thts true, but for now its only 3000 records, so guess this would work

Comment: @user3617463 Why design slow things until being slow is a problem? Let us know how format() is working for you when you have 3 million or billion rows...